# Pandas groupby columns without multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a data about train stations in a month, of which three are indexes: Station, Date, Hour. 
I could look like this:

```
Station    Date       Hour    Passengers 
Berlin HBF 2012-12-24 12:00   1000 
Berlin HBF 2012-12-24 13:00   2000  
Berlin HBF 2012-12-24 14:00   1000  
Berlin HBF 2012-12-24 15:00   1000  
....
Stuttgart 2012-12-24 12:00    500
```

Since I am only interested in sums for a station in a month, I would like to groupby by Station, Date, and Hour, so that the end result looks like this:

```
Station    Passengers 
Berlin HBF 4000 
....
Stuttgart  500
```

But I am unable to get pandas to this solution, I tried:
byStation = traindata.groupby(['Station', 'Date', 'Hour']).agg(np.sum())
But that simply returns a multiindex, with all rows...

Comment: Looks like you want to group by "Station" only and do a sum over the "Passangers"-column. You do not need a multi-index here (you solution will create one, but as it is the same one as your raw data, it's quite useless)

Comment: Ugh, now I see the error. Thank you such much!
Could you add your comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to group by "Station" only and do a sum over the "Passangers"-column. You do not need a multi-index here. Your solution will create one, but as it is the same one as your raw data, it's quite useless.

This one should work:

```
traindata.groupby("Station").Passengers.sum()
```